# Katakana to Hiragana in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, selection, string-conversion

I have an excel file where I have to change Katakana characters to Hiragana. I've been using `StrConv` + `vbHiragana` for some time, however, it is really slow since I am using it in a range for a 1000 rows (two times). After searching around, I've found the following code, which seems like a different approach and looks really fast. My only problem is, that it only works if I select the specified row and column (e.g. from `A1:A10`) and then if I run it, it does the job perfectly. I need to tweak this so it automatically does it in a range and displays the results on a different sheet.　(From `A1:A1000` + `D1:D1000`)
Like this:

[image: sample]

Here is the code I've found:

```
Sub Comm()
Dim i, gyos, retus, rwsu As Integer
Dim KATA, HIRA As String


gyos = ActiveCell.Row
retus = ActiveCell.Column
rwsu = Selection.Rows.Count - 1


For n = gyos To gyos + rwsu
KATA = Cells(n, retus)
HIRA = StrConv(KATA, 32)
Cells(n, retus) = HIRA
Next n


End Sub
```

Anyone knows a way around this?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `selection`. Set your own range.

Comment: Sorry, I cant follow your question, could you revisit it and see if you could make it clearer and someone may be able to help better.

Comment: I'll try my best! 

Like the picture I've provided, Sheet 1 contains the original data with kanji + katakana characters. Katakana characters are in column B and column D.
I need to change these characters and display the results on Sheet 2 in the same columns. The code I have found works okay - if I put Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(n, retus) = HIRA in the end, it even displays it on the rights sheet. However, the macro only works if I manually select rows. I think it has to do with the "ActiveCell" part..however, I am not sure how to solve that. Also, I need to run it in both B&D columns.

Comment: Can you translate your variable names to english (especially gyos, retus and rwsu)

Comment: Also, edit your original post instead of adding precision in the comments please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what findwindow suggested, just set your own range and use that in the `for` loop:

```
Dim row as Integer

For row = 1 to 1000
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row).Value = StrConv(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row).Value, 32)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & row).Value = StrConv(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & row).Value, 32)
Next row
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a little more simpler..

```
Sub Comm()
    Dim iRng As Range, uRng As Range

    Set uRng = Union(Range("A1:A1000"), Range("D1:D1000"))

    For Each iRng In uRng

        iRng = StrConv(iRng, vbHiragana)

    Next iRng

End Sub
```

Kanpai~

Comment: Thank you for the solution!! This one also works and sped up my whole file about 50%!